# How Bootstrap makes just Modal to scroll & not others?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm creating a modal like Bootstrap & everything is OK. The only thing I noticed is that Bootstrap prevent overflowing of BODY Tag when modal opens But modal has this property to overflow if the content in modal is more than the height of screen ..., How did that ? I added overflow: hidden; to body when modal opens & overflow: auto; to modal, But It doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, once you take a HTML element out of the normal flow of elements, it's father element shouldn't effect the element itself.

So, the body has a `overflow: hidden;`, but since the overlay is positioned outside of the flow, the `overflow` doesn't effect it.

Since `.overlay` have `overflow-y: auto`, a scroll should appear specifically for the content of this element.

So, once an element is positioned with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, it shouldn't be effected by it's predecessor's `overflow`

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="modal">I'm a long modal</div>
</div>


Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll. Everything here should not scroll.
```

Here's an external [demo](http://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/JKpazZ)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is adding `overflow` to your modal's content area.  If you look at Bootstrap's structure it is along the lines of:

```
<modal>
  <modal-header></modal-header>
  <modal-contents>
    Your content here
  </modal-contents>
  <modal-footer></modal-footer>
</modal>
```

The modal itself has a maximum height, and the child elements (header, contents, footer) all have fixed heights, with the content area having an overflow.

Eerily appropriate might be this recent article on CSS-Tricks:

https://css-tricks.com/considerations-styling-modal/

Comment: Thanks Robert for your response, I added overflow: auto; to my modal-content but It didn't work ...